# Zeppelin on AWS EC2 (Ubuntu instance)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, apache-zeppelin

I installed Apache Spark and Zeppelin on an Ubuntu instance running on AWS. Zeppelin is starting fine and when I check the status it is OK:

```
sudo ./bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh status

Zeppelin is running                                        [  OK  ]
```

But I can not use the "ip address":8090 to see the zeppelin webpage and create notebooks. The IP address I am using is the public one AWS give me (and I changed the port to 8090 in zeppelin-site.xml).

Should I change the server address in the zeppelin-site.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zeppelin is indeed running on port 8090 on that server, but the port is not accessible externally -- that is, it can only be accessed from the server itself.

No fear! You can use **port forwarding** to connect to it.

**Linux**

```
ssh -i keypair.pem -L 8090:localhost:8090 user@<IP-ADDRESS>
```

This tells SSH to forward any requests sent to port 8090 on the local computer to the remote machine's `localhost:8090`. Therefore, you can access Zeppelin via `localhost:8090` on your computer.

Here's an example of it in use: [Big Data: Amazon EMR, Apache Spark and Apache Zeppelin – Part 2 of 2](http://cloudacademy.com/blog/big-data-getting-started-with-amazon-emr-apache-spark-and-apache-zeppelin-part-two-of-two/)

**PuTTy**

If you are using PuTTY to connect to the host, there is a similar command in the **Tunnels** configuration screen. Redirect 8090 to `localhost:8090` on the remote machine.

Comment: Great! I wanted to create a notebook and send the url to my boss and ask him to run it on his machine. Now should i tell him run the ssh -L first then use the local url?

Comment: Well, that's how I access it on Amazon EMR. You could try accessing Zepplin directly (`server:8090`) after opening the port in the Security Group and see whether you can use it. The [Hortonworks configuration instructions for Zeppelin](https://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/apache-zeppelin-hdp-2-4/) actually show this as normal.